# How to skip the upgrade to Oreo

Tags: updates, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7

My Galaxy S7 downloaded the Oreo upgrade, and now a notification persists in my status bar and every now and then it pops up asking me to upgrade. I don't want to upgrade. Is there a way to skip upgrading without rooting or factory reset? 
I tried deleting cache and disabling the software upgrade app but it didn't work, and there's no option to disable the app.

[image]

Comment: If any settings available to disable background data of Software update app?

Comment: No :-/ even the existing settings are disabled

Comment: I have the same problem on a German Samsung phone: https://imgur.com/a/fvx0WDz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by buying [Package Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.powermanager.batteryaddon&hl=en) and disabling the Software Update app.